# Have any other bowlers reached the same test wickets milestone by dismissing the same batsman?

Tags: cricket, trivia

During the [3rd Test of the West Indies tour of England in 2020](https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/19497/scorecard/1225249/england-vs-west-indies-3rd-test-west-indies-in-england-2020), Stuart Broad reached 500 test career wickets by dismissing Kraigg Brathwaite.

James Anderson also reached 500 test wickets by dismissing Kraigg Brathwaite, during the 3rd Test of the West Indies tour of England in 2017.

**Have any other bowler pair reached the same wickets milestone by dismissing the same player?**

---

To clarify a few points:

- I do not mean "Has anyone else reached 500 wickets by dismissing Kraigg Brathwaite" - I mean has Bowler B reached a milestone, also made by Bowler A, by dismissing the same batsman.
- I'll define a "Milestone" as one of the hundreds - i.e. 100, 200, 300 wickets etc.
- By "Bowler Pair", I just mean any two bowlers - they can play for any country; but bonus points if they are from the same country.
- This is mainly aimed at Test wickets, but if there is an occasion in ODIs or T20Is then that's good too.